# Cannot view contents of remote directory in Explorer View with VS Code Remote SSH

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, ssh, artificial-intelligence, remote-server

I am connecting to a remote server via ssh in vs code using remote ssh by microsoft. My terminal is opening fine but I am unable to view the contents of my remote directory in the vs code explorer. I am using ventura OS of Macbook.
Output of the logs -

```
15:21:10.600] Log Level: 2
[15:21:10.608] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+ada.iiit.ac.in", attempt 1
[15:21:10.609] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true
[15:21:10.609] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": false
[15:21:10.609] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[15:21:10.609] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[15:21:10.609] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[15:21:10.609] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[15:21:10.609] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[15:21:10.609] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[15:21:10.609] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[15:21:10.609] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[15:21:10.609] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[15:21:10.609] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[15:21:10.609] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[15:21:10.610] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[15:21:10.610] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[15:21:10.611] VS Code version: 1.83.1
[15:21:10.611] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.106.5
[15:21:10.611] darwin arm64
[15:21:10.613] SSH Resolver called for host: ada.iiit.ac.in
[15:21:10.613] Setting up SSH remote "ada.iiit.ac.in"
[15:21:10.615] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/38/42jnccns6sg2x4g_542rfj480000gn/T/vscode-remote-ssh-971bab23-install.lock
[15:21:10.615] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/souvikg544/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-971bab23-f1b07bd25dfad64b0167beb15359ae573aecd2cc-0.106.5-tr/data.json
[15:21:10.616] Found local server running: {"remoteListeningOn":{"port":43206},"osReleaseId":"centos","arch":"x86_64","webUiAccessToken":"","sshAuthSock":"","display":"","tmpDir":"/run/user/3027","platform":"linux","connectionToken":"aa111111-a1a1-1aa1-1aaa-11a1a11aa11a","pid":7341,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/38/42jnccns6sg2x4g_542rfj480000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-6662b95f3709310bdd87ae4c4ddfbcd05eaf34e9.sock","socksPort":51136,"startupTime":1697622294618}
[15:21:10.619] Found running server - short-circuiting install
[15:21:10.620] Starting forwarding server. local port 51202 -> socksPort 51136 -> remotePort 43206
[15:21:10.620] Forwarding server listening on port 51202
[15:21:10.621] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[15:21:10.621] Tunneled port 43206 to local port 51202
[15:21:10.621] Resolved "ssh-remote+ada.iiit.ac.in" to "port 51202"
[15:21:10.622] [Forwarding server port 51202] Got connection 0
[15:21:10.627] ------




[15:21:10.636] [Forwarding server port 51202] Got connection 1
[15:21:10.718] [Forwarding server port 51202] Got connection 2
[15:21:11.025] [Forwarding server port 51202] Got connection 3
[15:21:11.221] [Forwarding server port 51202] Got connection 4
```

Below is an image that shows the problem. You can see that on the left side in the explorer an empty tab shows instead of the files and directories. The terminal is also not connecting on some instances as in the image below
[image: Screenshot of vs Code terminal]